# jquery.load google map struggling

Tags: ajax, api, google-maps, load

Hey trying to load my google map through a jquery load call... doesn't seem to be loading on to my div on my index page through an external page.. had the code from the google developers page.. but cant seem to get it to work.. any help or pointers that would be great...

```
$('#content').on('click', 'nav ul li a', function() {

    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    // Script to fade and show pages
            $('#content').hide().load('page/' + page + '.php').fadeIn('normal', function() {

                  function initialize() {
                          var mapOptions = {
                            zoom: 8,
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                          }
                          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
                        }

                        function loadScript() {
                          var script = document.createElement("script");
                          script.type = "text/javascript";
                          script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE&callback=initialize";
                          document.body.appendChild(script);
                        }

                        window.onload = loadScript;
                        });
            });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `window.onload` when it is already over.

Change `window.onload = loadScript;` to just `loadScript();`

Comment: nope didnt work having a bit of a night mare this is what ive got http://pastie.org/private/6jmfuqvvg9t50viwnqzfqa i wanna load external pages into a main index page with a dive where the external pages get loaded to. hope that makes sense.. just cant seem to call any jave scripts or anything when the page loads.. for example cant call the google map to load with the external pages when they get loaded into the main index div..